# Symfony embed image forms in admin generator

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I use symfony with doctrine. So I use [this](http://sandbox-ws.com/2009/01/how-to-embed-forms-in-symfony-12-admin-generator-part-2/) tutorial ([google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHbz45FG-ZqQJ%3asandboxws.com/how-to-embed-forms-in-symfony-12-admin-genera-53021%20how-to-embed-forms-in-symfony-1.2-admin-generator-part-2/&hl=uk&client=opera&gl=ua&strip=1)). So I have category and subcategory I make next :

```
 if (!$this->isNew()) {

    // embed all subcategory forms
    foreach ($this->getObject()->getSubcategory() as $subcategory) {

    // create a new subcategory form for the current subcategory model object
    $subcategory_form = new SubcategoryForm($subcategory);

    // embed the subcategory form in the main category form
    $this->embedForm('subcategory'.$subcategory->getId(), $subcategory_form);

    // set a custom label for the embedded form
    $this->widgetSchema['subcategory'.$subcategory->getId()]->setLabel('Subcategory:'. $subcategory->getName());

}

$subcategory_form = new SubcategoryForm();

  // embed the subcategory form in the main category form
 $this->embedForm('subcategory', $subcategory_form);

 public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null) {

    $this->languages = sfConfig::get('app_cultures_enabled');

    $langs = array_keys($this->languages);

       foreach($this->languages as $lang => $label)
            {
    // remove the embedded new form if the name field was not provided
    if (is_null($taintedValues['subcategory'][$lang]['name']) || strlen($taintedValues ['subcategory'][$lang]['name']) === 0 ) {

        unset($this->embeddedForms['subcategory'], $taintedValues['subcategory']);

        // pass the new form validations
        $this->validatorSchema['subcategory'] = new sfValidatorPass();

    } else {

        // set the category of the new subcategory form object
        $this->embeddedForms['subcategory']->getObject()->
                setCategory($this->getObject());

    }
            }

    // call parent bind method
    parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);

}
```

Ok so this method works. But I want to make same for but not for subcategory, I want to make it for image form. So I have next:

```
if (!$this->isNew()) {

                // Image

                    foreach ($this->getObject()->getImage() as $image) {

                            $image_form = new ImageForm($image);
                            $this->embedForm('image'.$image->getId(), $image_form);

                 }


                $image_form = new ImageForm();

                $this->embedForm('image', $image_form);

 public function bind(array $taintedValues = null, array $taintedFiles = null) {

     if (is_null($taintedValues['image']['image'])|| strlen($taintedValues['image']['image']) === 0 ) {

                  unset($this->embeddedForms['image'], $taintedValues['image']);

                    // pass the new form validations
                   $this->validatorSchema['image'] = new sfValidatorPass();

                } else {

                            // set the category of the new subcategory form object
                            $this->embeddedForms['image']->getObject()->
                            setProduct($this->getObject());                        
    }
 parent::bind($taintedValues, $taintedFiles);


  }
```

But in this way my image form unset in any way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand my last sentence... you should var_dump tainted values and tainted files in order to debug

Comment: thank you! I make print_r, and  find answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make :

```
 if ((''== $taintedFiles['image']['image']['name']) ) {

                  unset($this->embeddedForms['image'], $taintedValues['image'],$taintedFiles['image']);

                    // pass the new form validations
                   $this->validatorSchema['image'] = new sfValidatorPass();

                }
```